# C(n,r) calculator program doesn't work

Tags: java, coding-style

I made a C(n,r) calculator using java Netbeans JFrameform.

[here is the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4VqH.jpg)

Here is the code :-

```
private void lllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int n=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
    int r=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
    int s=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i+1){
        s=i*s;
    }
    int p=1;
    for(int j=1;j<=n-r;j=j+1){
        p=j*p;
    }
    int q=1;
    for(int k=1;k<=r;k=k+1){
        q=k*q;
    }
    int re=s/(p*q);
    t3.setText(" "+re);
}
```

the code works well for values values of n upto 12. But for 13 and onward , code starts giving wrong answer.

[wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld1zo.jpg)

why is this happening? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the calculations the value goes over [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) This is an [overflow of arithmetic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

> Integer overflow can be demonstrated through an odometer overflowing, a mechanical version of the phenomenon. All digits are set to the maximum 9 and the next increment of the white digit causes a cascade of carry-over additions setting all digits to 0, but there is no higher digit to change to a 1, so the counter resets to zero. This is wrapping in contrast to saturating.
>   In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the range that can be represented with a given number of bits – either larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

Try to replace `int` with `long` values. It will work with a greater value.

```
private void lllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int n=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
    int r=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
    int s=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i+1){
        s=i*s;
    }
    long p=1L;
    for(int j=1;j<=n-r;j=j+1){
        p=j*p;
    }
    long q=1L;
    for(int k=1;k<=r;k=k+1){
        q=k*q;
    }
    long re=s/(p*q);
    t3.setText(" "+re);
}
```

With 14 and 2 as inputs the result is 91.

If you want to have a correct result for big values you have to use a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) that handle:

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers

Comment: thanks,it solved the problem.
But integer has a range of 0 to 65,535, right?
how did that limit got crossed in calculating C(n,r)?
i would like to know.

Comment: Integer are in the range -2 147 483 648 +2 147 483 647. The problem is that in the operations inside the for bodies you make some multiplications, for example s = i * s or p = j * p and q = k * q. Those multiplications generate very big numbers because are continuosly multiplying  the same value in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
private void lllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int n=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
    int r=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
    if (r > n / 2) r = n - r; // because C(n, r) == C(n, n - r)
    long ans = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        ans *= n - r + i;
        ans /= i;
    }

    t3.setText(" "+ans);
}
```

Comment: yes your code works. But i would like to know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: You are getting integer overflow.